# CSS: Can't target div with specific attribute using nth-child

Tags: css

I'm working with some less-than-ideal legacy blog code where I am trying to target the first div that has an attribute of "text-align: left". Here's a stripped-down typical example of what I'm working with:

```
<div class="et_pb_module et_pb_post_content et_pb_post_content_0_tb_body">              
  <div style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
  <div style="text-align: center;"><i>There is always a glimmer in those</i></div>
  <div style="text-align: center;"><i>who have been through the dark.</i></div>
  <div style="text-align: center;"><i>&nbsp;</i></div>
  <div style="text-align: center;">Atticus</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div style="text-align: left;">TARGET ME PLEASE</div>
  <div style="text-align: left;">More text in another "paragraph"</div>
  ...
</div>
```

My understanding is that this should work, but it doesn't:

```
.et_pb_post_content div[style="text-align: left;"]:nth-child(1) {
    clear:both;
}
```

But it doesn't work... can someone tell me why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove the semi-colon like below;

`[style="text-align: left"]`

Comment: Hmmm. When I try this (avoiding the "nth-child" issue for the time being): `.et_pb_post_content div[style="text-align: left;"] {color: red;}` - with the semicolon - it turns all the expected text red. With NO semicolon, that doesn't work.

Comment: You ought to try removing the semi-colon when using the nth-child `.et_pb_post_content div[style="text-align: left"]:nth-child(1)`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now trying `.et_pb_post_content div[style="text-align: left"]:nth-child(1) {color: red;}` but it's affecting ALL the div's with that style... I just want to affect the first one (that appears within the .et_pb_post_content div, that is). Isn't nth-child(1) the way to reach it?

Comment: @AdamAbrams the pseudo-class selector makes this a bit tricky as they use structure order in relation to parent and sibling. The div you want to target is not the div child in the order so it is not targeted, If you change `:nth-child(odd)` it targets all odd children see (link)[https://codepen.io/Anurella/pen/JjyxoLp] for example.

Reference 
(:nth-child)[https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/]

Comment: Thanks, I've had a close look at those links. But I'm still puzzled, IS there a way to target that first div with the style of "text-align: left"? Also I don't understand "The div you want to target is not the div child in the order". It's the first div with that style, within the enclosing (.et_pb_post_content) div, so I"m still unsure why I can't target it... sorry!